# How to maintain a list of files uploaded by the user with streamlit?

Tags: python, streamlit

I would like to have a web app that lets the user add and remove files from their computer. All I need is the names of the files. all the computation on these files will be done locally. I would like to have a list of these file names and let the user add and remove names from that list. I would also like to have a list of these file names so I could save and load this list whenever I want.
I achieved that using tkinter's filedialog and listbox but I dont know how to do that with streamlit. How can I keep track if the user decided to remove one of the uploaded files?

```
chosen_file = sl.file_uploader("Upload inp:", type='inp', accept_multiple_files=True)
for inp in chosen_inp_files:
    if inp is not None:
        inp_lsit.append(inp.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the streamlit.file_uploader function to allow users to upload files and store their names in a list. You can then display the list of file names using a Streamlit component such as st.write or st.table. To allow users to remove file names from the list, you can provide a button or checkbox for each file name that the user can interact with.

Example:

```py
import streamlit as st

# Create a list to store the uploaded file names
file_list = []

# Use the file_uploader to allow users to upload files
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Upload Files", accept_multiple_files=True)

# Loop through the uploaded files
for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
    if uploaded_file is not None:
        # Append the name of the uploaded file to the file_list
        file_list.append(uploaded_file.name)

# Display the list of uploaded file names
st.write("Uploaded Files:")
for file_name in file_list:
    # Provide a checkbox for each file name to allow users to remove files
    remove_file = st.checkbox(file_name)
    if remove_file:
        # Remove the file name from the file_list if the checkbox is selected
        file_list.remove(file_name)

# Save or load the file_list as needed
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a list of files uploaded by the user with Streamlit by creating an empty list and appending the file names to it whenever a user uploads a file. Here's some example code:

```
import streamlit as st

# Create an empty list to store uploaded files
uploaded_files = []

# Add a file uploader to your Streamlit app
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a file", type=["txt", "pdf"])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    # Append the file name to the list of uploaded files
    uploaded_files.append(uploaded_file.name)
    st.success(f"{uploaded_file.name} uploaded successfully!")

# Display the list of uploaded files
if uploaded_files:
    st.write("List of uploaded files:")
    for file in uploaded_files:
        st.write(file)
```

This code creates an empty list called uploaded_files, adds a file uploader to the Streamlit app, and appends the name of each uploaded file to the list. It also displays a success message when a file is uploaded and a list of all uploaded files. You can customize this code to suit your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem, the code below may help you the method show_files only shows files in a directory with a check box and the second method just remove the files which are selected by the check box. The check box state is saved together with the file name in a dictionary.

```
import streamlit as st
import os

if 'source_files' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['source_files'] = {}

def show_files(path):
   # st.session_state['source_files'] = {}
   for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
       st.session_state['source_files'].update({file: st.checkbox(file)})


def remove_files(path):
   key_list = []
   for key, val in st.session_state['source_files'].items():
       if val:
           key_list.append(key)
           os.remove('{}\\{}'.format(path, key))
   for key in key_list:
       st.session_state['source_files'].pop(key)
   st.rerun()
```